# How to select CamelCase words in Mysql RegexP

Tags: mysql, regex

In 'plain' Regex this works for me:

```
\w+[A-Z][a-z]\w+
```

as per this example: https://regex101.com/r/VqsTXL/1

However doing the equivalent in Regexp fails to find CamelCase:

```
[[:<:]][A-Z][a-z][[:>:]]
```

as per this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad35d8/1

Comment: Try `^[[:alnum:]]+[[:upper:]][[:lower:]][[:alnum:]]+$` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad35d8/17/0

Comment: The general regex ([A-Z][a-z]+)* matches CamelCase and does not match exclusive Uppercase, add bounds as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL version before 8, you can "emulate" `\w` using `[[:alnum:]_]`:

```
Select * from PatternTester where Binary Name  regexp '[[:alnum:]_]+[A-Z][a-z][[:alnum:]_]+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTys5U/1).

SQL:

```
Create Table PatternTester
(Name varchar(100));
Insert into PatternTester  (Name)
values ('CamelCase'),
('Camelcase'), 
('CAMELCASE'), 
('CamelCase')

Select * from PatternTester where Binary Name  regexp '[[:alnum:]_]+[A-Z][a-z][[:alnum:]_]+'
```

See [SQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d50cb5/1).

Comment: @Thanks, selected your answer. However, I'm having trouble in my actual db as it i sfinding in text blocks things like ` 1974 ` and ` 70% `.  I even chanted to `[[:alpha:]]` to no avail. However as you can see in your example those are not found: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a82fd1/1 so is there some limitaiton based on MySql version or setting do you think?

Comment: @user3649739 This is not possible to match `70%` with the above regex in any flavor. You must have an issue somewhere else.